# Can't initialise ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Very simple error I'm sure, just having a mental block for some reason!

I have an object which contains an ArrayList of other objects. When I try to initialise the list in the constructor it does not seem to initialise and I get a nullpointer when I attempt to access the list within the code.

Order class variables:

```
private int covers;
    private int table;
    private ArrayList<MenuItem> items;
```

Here is the Order class:

```
public Order(int covers, int table) {
    super();
    this.covers = covers;
    this.table = table;
    this.items = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
}
```

Here is the code within the MainActivity causing me problems:

```
order = new Order();
    order.setCovers(2);
    order.setTable(1);
    order.addToOrder(new MenuItem("Item 1", 12.99));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "order size: " + order.getItems().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I would expect the Toast to display "1". However when I ran debugger I noticed the order object ArrayList attribute was equal to null.

Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: addToOrder method:

```
public void addToOrder(MenuItem m){
    items.add(m);
}
```

Comment: can you show us your `addToOrder` method?

Comment: @mango I updated my question with the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have failed to initialize  `items`. Use

```
vorder = new Order(int1, int2);
```

instead of

```
vorder = new Order();
```

`items` is initialized inside

```
public Order(int covers, int table) {

}
```

not on the default constructor.

Comment: Your answer made me see my mistake. The problem was I was calling the default constructor and not initializing items within the constructor. Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Parcelable interface by any chance?

Comment: Yes I am. It is my favorite when trying to pass objects between activities.

Comment: I am successfully passing the Order object between two activities. However when I try to pass the object with the arraylist I get an error. I can read the arraylist into the parcel fine using `dest.writeList(items);`. However I don't know how to retrieve it from the parcel using `readArrayList(loader);`. Would you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Can not tell with just these info. Could you a create a new question if you havent yet.

Comment: Here is my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249468/trying-to-retrieve-data-from-parcel